# URL mapping in Python/Django

Tags: python, django

I just started to learn Django and Python.

I use the online book from [djangobook.com](http://djangobook.com)

In chapter 3, (http://djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter03/) I am trying out the sample to add x hours to current time. My files below:

`urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from mysite.views import current_datetime

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^time/$', current_datetime),
    (r'^time/plus/(\d{1,2})/$', hours_ahead),
)
```

`views.py`

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime

def current_datetime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    html = "<html><body>It is now %s.</body></html>" % now
    return HttpResponse(html)

def hours_ahead(request, offset):
    offset = int(offset)
    dt = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=offset)
    html = "<html><body>In %s hour(s), it will be %s.</body></html>" % (offset, dt)
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

But if I try to navigate to: http://127.0.0.1:8000/time/plus/5/, I get a `NameError at /time/plus/5/`. Am I missing something?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Dump here - http://pastebin.com/Hn3aFLzR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forget to import `hours_ahead` in urls.py:

```
from mysite.views import current_datetime, hours_ahead
```